# Desactivar s:select struct

Tags: struct

Tengo el siguiente select de struct:

```
<s:select name="idDepartamento" cssClass="form-control" id="idDepartamento"
 list="@com.mncars.factura.negocio.GestionDepartamentos@dameDepartamentos()"
 listKey="idDepartamento"
 listValue="departamento"
 headerKey="" headerValue="-- Seleccione --"
 value="%{#session.deptUsuario.idDepartamento}" 
 readonly="true"
/>
```

Simplemente quiero que sea de lectura, pero la propiedad `readonly` no funciona correctamente, es decir el componente se ve gris como si estuviera desactivado pero puedo cambiar de opcion.

Tambien he probado con `disable` pero este no hace nada.

¿Alguno sabe que ocurre?

Comment: Yo lo hice con jQuery. Si necesitas que esté deshabilitado desde un inicio puedes usar $(document).ready(function(){ $("#idDepartamento").prop("disabled", true); });

Comment: Ya intentaste con disabled="true"? Según la documentación debería funcionar con eso

Comment: @user2930137 con Jquery si lo desactiva, pero quería que directamente el componente estuviera inactivo desde la construccion del componente, aun asi gracias.